# Empty list of dictionaries ios 9.3.2 - 9.3.3. iPad mini

Tags: ios, ipad, dictionary

In safari, ibooks, notes there is no any dictionary to show/download after define and manage. Just empty list of rows. Reset all settings and update from 9.3.2 to 9.3.3 not help. It happened after update from 8 to 9 ios. [image]

Comment: This same question was posted yesterday. Have you tried contacting Apple Support? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247948/ios-9-3-3-no-dictionaries

Comment: I have same problem, and my apple support has expired.

Comment: This was due to iOS bug pointing at wrong dictionaries feed URL. Apple now publishing dictionaries at that feed so should be working again automatically for users:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/30518515
(Not enough rep to post as answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating of the iOS to 9.3.4 and then changing region or language or both (i change both and get references to download all dictionaries.
I think that Apple support team have heard us)