# 6S Plus iOS 9.3.4 no dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, iphone

The iPhone 6S plus has no dictionary. No matter which app I'm in. If I highlight a word and ask to define it it shows no results. I click manage to try add dictionary and nothing shows up. There is no list just an empty page. This happens in EVERY app. How can this be rectified?

I have tried resetting keyboard dictionary, reset all settings, restoring the phone. All to no avail.

Comment: Did you try Google? or even search the site here? http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=iOS%20dictionary This seems best so far - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247948/ios-9-3-3-no-dictionaries

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem with both my iphone 6S and Ipad2.
I have also tried it all, removing languages and re-playing them. And restoring my Iphone and Ipad. Someone help, plss Exactly like this:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7627307

Answer (score 1):

Change region or language or both. (I solved the same problem by updating of the iOS to 9.3.4 and then changing region or language or both (i change both and get references to download all dictionaries)